# Python 3.11.0 Import sqlite not found

Tags: python, modules, sqlite

I've tried

```
python -m pip install -U sqlite
```

it returns

```
No matching distribution found for sqlite
```

I'm using python 3.11.0

Comment: What research have you done to solve the issue?

Comment: If you had used the standard version of Python you would not have this problem.

Comment: is the standard version not 3.11.0? is it 3.10.0?

Comment: The standard version is 3.9.2

Comment: ok i will switch

Answer (score 3):

The module is named `sqlite3`, not `sqlite`.

`sqlite3` is built into Python's standard library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), you should not try to install it using pip.

If `import sqlite3` does not work either, it means you've compiled Python without SQLite support, and you need to build it again after installing the [libsqlite3-dev](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libsqlite3-dev) package.